# Reset System Loop

Tags: boot, boot-repair

after a reboot my Acer Laptop is stuck on a boot loop, in the upper left corner also appear the message "Reset System", I tried reinstalling ubuntu but this didn't solve the problem.
I used boot-repair and pasted the log here:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/n8x8SBwpS9/

What can I do?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Not quite clear how you installed it, but you have an uefi partition - so probably an UEFI on your hardware as well, so Ubuntu needs to be installed in uefi mode -if not legacy mode is turned on in your bios).  Did you do this?

Comment: I created the bootable usb stick for Ubuntu using rufus, then in uefi mode installed it, then after reboot I got the error again. I installed boot-repair using rufus, but in uefi mode I couldn't find the usb, then I changed to legacy mode and it worked. Ubuntu doesn't work in legacy mode (I get an error, the error is something like it doesn't find a system)

Comment: Correct -if Ubuntu has been installed in uefi mode, your repair stick must be uefi also. Why using rufus? Using dd in terminal is the most efficent way to create an usb stick. You need to tell your uefi about the usb stick....

Comment: I will try using dd as soon as I can, I used Rufus cause i already had it on my windows computer and never gave problems
Anyway the "reset system" message was there before reinstalling Ubuntu, so I think it has something to do with uefi, but I'm not an expert

Comment: I found a quick solution at Reddit.
There need to copy a file from EFI folder to BOOT folder like this:

    cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Put "ubuntu" at the top of your boot priority list. Linpus Lite is for booting Ubuntu when the secure boot is off.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This issue is because the boot files need to be repaired, I had the same problem , researched everything didn't find a solution  until I went to my windows OS and downloaded free version of easy easybcd then I went to bcd backup/repair then re-create /repair boot files
And everything worked the "reset system loop "nolonger displays

Comment: From the comments it seems that the asker doesn't have Windows installed on his Acer laptop.

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem:

I made a simple mistake, of not enabling the hard drive.

In the Boot Settings menu, I noticed that I had set all boot options to Disabled, except for the USB drive.

By

- enabling the hard drive as a boot option (which was where I had installed Ubuntu)
- and placing the hard drive at the top of the boot order

I was able to successfully boot into the new Operating System (OS)

Answer (score -1):

**Boot Ubuntu from live USB**

Open a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-update      
sudo apt install boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Advanced options -> Tick reinstall Grub and don't touch anything else - click Apply.